# Hadoop 2.7.2 RM WebUI doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I can not access the RessourceManager WebUI usually running on `http://ressourcemanager:8088/cluster`. Chrome showing me page doesn't work: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Can't find any missconfiguration or log telling me whats wrong. I cannot see any `:8088` on `netstat -la`.

**mapred site**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <!-- The runtime framework for executing MapReduce jobs. Can be one of local, classic or yarn. -->
    <!-- Default-VALUE: local -->
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
    <!-- The local directory where MapReduce stores intermediate data files. May be a comma-separated list of directories on different devices in order to spread disk i/o. Directories that do not exist are ignored. -->
    <!-- Default-VALUE: ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/local -->
    <name>mapreduce.cluster.local.dir</name>
    <value>${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/local</value>
</property>

<property>
    <!-- The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs at. If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map and reduce task. -->
    <!-- Default-VALUE: local -->
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
    <value>node01:8020</value>
</property>
<property>
    <!-- The directory where MapReduce stores control files. -->
    <!-- Default-VALUE: ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/system -->
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.system.dir</name>
    <value>${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/system</value>
</property>
<property> 
    <!-- The job tracker http server address and port the server will listen on. If the port is 0 then the server will start on a free port. -->
    <!-- Default-VALUE: 0.0.0.0:50030 -->
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address</name>
    <value>node01:50030</value> 
</property>

<property> 
    <!-- The task tracker http server address and port. If the port is 0 then the server will start on a free port. -->
    <!-- Default-VALUE: 0.0.0.0:50060 -->
    <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.http.address</name>
    <value>node01:50060</value> 
</property>

<property> 
    <!-- MapReduce JobHistory Server IPC host:port -->
    <!-- Default-VALUE: 0.0.0.0:10020 -->
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
    <value>node01:10020</value> 
</property>
<property> 
    <!-- MapReduce JobHistory Server Web UI host:port -->
    <!-- Default-VALUE: 0.0.0.0:19888 -->
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>node01:19888</value> 
</property>
```

**yarn site**

```
<configuration>
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
<!-- RessourceManager configuration -->
<property>
<!-- The hostname of the RM. -->
<!-- Default-VALUE: 0.0.0.0 -->
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>node01</value>
</property>
<property>
<!-- The address of the applications manager interface in the RM. -->
<!-- Default-VALUE: ${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8032 -->
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
<!-- The address of the scheduler interface. -->
<!-- Default-VALUE: ${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8030 -->
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
<!-- XXX -->
<!-- Default-VALUE: ${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8031 -->
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8031</value>
</property>
<property>
<!-- The address of the RM admin interface. -->
<!-- Default-VALUE: ${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8033 -->
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
<value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8033</value>
</property>
<property>
<!-- The http address of the RM web application. -->
<!-- Default-VALUE: ${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8088 -->
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
<value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8088</value>
</property>
<property>
<!-- The class to use as the resource scheduler. -->
<!-- Default-VALUE: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler -->
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler</value>
</property>
<property>
<!-- A comma separated list of services where service name should only contain a-zA-Z0-9_ and can not start with number -->
<!-- Default-VALUE: -->
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-node01-log**

```
 /************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down ResourceManager at node01/192.168.3.11
************************************************************/
2016-07-19 16:18:56,507 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting ResourceManager
STARTUP_MSG:   host = node01/192.168.3.11
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.7.2
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r b165c4fe8a74265c792ce23f546c64604acf0e41; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2016-01-26T00:08Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_92
************************************************************/
2016-07-19 16:18:56,526 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2016-07-19 16:18:56,736 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: found resource core-site.xml at file:/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
2016-07-19 16:18:56,776 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups: clearing userToGroupsMap cache
2016-07-19 16:18:56,865 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: found resource yarn-site.xml at file:/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml
2016-07-19 16:18:56,969 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMFatalEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$RMFatalEventDispatcher
2016-07-19 16:18:57,080 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM: NMTokenKeyRollingInterval: 86400000ms and NMTokenKeyActivationDelay: 900000ms
2016-07-19 16:18:57,088 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMContainerTokenSecretManager: ContainerTokenKeyRollingInterval: 86400000ms and ContainerTokenKeyActivationDelay: 900000ms
2016-07-19 16:18:57,091 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.AMRMTokenSecretManager: AMRMTokenKeyRollingInterval: 86400000ms and AMRMTokenKeyActivationDelay: 900000 ms
2016-07-19 16:18:57,125 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStoreEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore$ForwardingEventHandler
2016-07-19 16:18:57,126 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.NodesListManagerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.NodesListManager
2016-07-19 16:18:57,126 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Using Scheduler: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler
2016-07-19 16:18:57,144 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.event.SchedulerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$SchedulerEventDispatcher
2016-07-19 16:18:57,144 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$ApplicationEventDispatcher
2016-07-19 16:18:57,145 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$ApplicationAttemptEventDispatcher
2016-07-19 16:18:57,146 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$NodeEventDispatcher
2016-07-19 16:18:57,231 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2016-07-19 16:18:57,275 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2016-07-19 16:18:57,275 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: ResourceManager metrics system started
2016-07-19 16:18:57,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManagerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager
2016-07-19 16:18:57,291 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncherEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.ApplicationMasterLauncher
2016-07-19 16:18:57,292 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMNMInfo: Registered RMNMInfo MBean
2016-07-19 16:18:57,294 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.security.YarnAuthorizationProvider: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.security.ConfiguredYarnAuthorizer is instiantiated.
2016-07-19 16:18:57,297 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.HostsFileReader: Refreshing hosts (include/exclude) list
2016-07-19 16:18:57,309 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: found resource capacity-scheduler.xml at file:/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/capacity-scheduler.xml
2016-07-19 16:18:57,346 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration: max alloc mb per queue for root is undefined
2016-07-19 16:18:57,346 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration: max alloc vcore per queue for root is undefined
2016-07-19 16:18:57,349 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: root, capacity=1.0, asboluteCapacity=1.0, maxCapacity=1.0, asboluteMaxCapacity=1.0, state=RUNNING, acls=SUBMIT_APP:*ADMINISTER_QUEUE:*, labels=*,
, reservationsContinueLooking=true
2016-07-19 16:18:57,349 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Initialized parent-queue root name=root, fullname=root
2016-07-19 16:18:57,356 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration: max alloc mb per queue for root.default is undefined
2016-07-19 16:18:57,356 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration: max alloc vcore per queue for root.default is undefined
2016-07-19 16:18:57,356 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: Initializing default
capacity = 1.0 [= (float) configuredCapacity / 100 ]
asboluteCapacity = 1.0 [= parentAbsoluteCapacity * capacity ]
maxCapacity = 1.0 [= configuredMaxCapacity ]
absoluteMaxCapacity = 1.0 [= 1.0 maximumCapacity undefined, (parentAbsoluteMaxCapacity * maximumCapacity) / 100 otherwise ]
userLimit = 100 [= configuredUserLimit ]
userLimitFactor = 1.0 [= configuredUserLimitFactor ]
maxApplications = 10000 [= configuredMaximumSystemApplicationsPerQueue or (int)(configuredMaximumSystemApplications * absoluteCapacity)]
maxApplicationsPerUser = 10000 [= (int)(maxApplications * (userLimit / 100.0f) * userLimitFactor) ]
usedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / (clusterResourceMemory * absoluteCapacity)]
absoluteUsedCapacity = 0.0 [= usedResourcesMemory / clusterResourceMemory]
maxAMResourcePerQueuePercent = 0.1 [= configuredMaximumAMResourcePercent ]
minimumAllocationFactor = 0.875 [= (float)(maximumAllocationMemory - minimumAllocationMemory) / maximumAllocationMemory ]
maximumAllocation = <memory:8192, vCores:32> [= configuredMaxAllocation ]
numContainers = 0 [= currentNumContainers ]
state = RUNNING [= configuredState ]
acls = SUBMIT_APP:*ADMINISTER_QUEUE:* [= configuredAcls ]
nodeLocalityDelay = 40
labels=*,
nodeLocalityDelay = 40
reservationsContinueLooking = true
preemptionDisabled = true

2016-07-19 16:18:57,356 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized queue: default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>, usedCapacity=0.0, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2016-07-19 16:18:57,357 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized queue: root: numChildQueue= 1, capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>usedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2016-07-19 16:18:57,357 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized root queue root: numChildQueue= 1, capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>usedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2016-07-19 16:18:57,357 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized queue mappings, override: false
2016-07-19 16:18:57,357 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized CapacityScheduler with calculator=class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator, minimumAllocation=<<memory:1024, vCores:1>>, maximumAllocation=<<memory:8192, vCores:32>>, asynchronousScheduling=false, asyncScheduleInterval=5ms
2016-07-19 16:18:57,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.metrics.SystemMetricsPublisher: YARN system metrics publishing service is not enabled
2016-07-19 16:18:57,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to active state
2016-07-19 16:18:57,436 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Updating AMRMToken
2016-07-19 16:18:57,436 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMContainerTokenSecretManager: Rolling master-key for container-tokens
2016-07-19 16:18:57,436 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM: Rolling master-key for nm-tokens
2016-07-19 16:18:57,436 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2016-07-19 16:18:57,437 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMDelegationTokenSecretManager: storing master key with keyID 1
2016-07-19 16:18:57,437 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Storing RMDTMasterKey.
2016-07-19 16:18:57,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Starting expired delegation token remover thread, tokenRemoverScanInterval=60 min(s)
2016-07-19 16:18:57,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2016-07-19 16:18:57,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMDelegationTokenSecretManager: storing master key with keyID 2
2016-07-19 16:18:57,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Storing RMDTMasterKey.
2016-07-19 16:18:57,440 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.nodelabels.event.NodeLabelsStoreEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.nodelabels.CommonNodeLabelsManager$ForwardingEventHandler
2016-07-19 16:18:57,633 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2016-07-19 16:18:57,654 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8031
2016-07-19 16:18:57,688 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.ResourceTrackerPB to the server
2016-07-19 16:18:57,688 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2016-07-19 16:18:57,690 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8031: starting
2016-07-19 16:18:58,151 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2016-07-19 16:18:58,175 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8030
2016-07-19 16:18:58,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationMasterProtocolPB to the server
2016-07-19 16:18:58,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2016-07-19 16:18:58,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8030: starting
2016-07-19 16:18:59,135 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2016-07-19 16:18:59,137 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocolPB to the server
2016-07-19 16:18:59,139 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8032
2016-07-19 16:18:59,139 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2016-07-19 16:18:59,146 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8032: starting
2016-07-19 16:18:59,187 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to active state
2016-07-19 16:18:59,367 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2016-07-19 16:18:59,374 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter: Unable to initialize FileSignerSecretProvider, falling back to use random secrets.
2016-07-19 16:18:59,379 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.resourcemanager is not defined
2016-07-19 16:18:59,482 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2016-07-19 16:18:59,498 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter RMAuthenticationFilter (class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter) to context cluster
2016-07-19 16:18:59,498 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter RMAuthenticationFilter (class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter) to context static
2016-07-19 16:18:59,498 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter RMAuthenticationFilter (class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter) to context logs
2016-07-19 16:18:59,499 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context cluster
2016-07-19 16:18:59,499 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2016-07-19 16:18:59,499 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2016-07-19 16:18:59,501 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /cluster/*
2016-07-19 16:18:59,502 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /ws/*
2016-07-19 16:19:00,236 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Registered webapp guice modules
2016-07-19 16:19:00,238 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 8088
2016-07-19 16:19:00,238 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2016-07-19 16:19:00,256 INFO org.mortbay.log: Extract jar:file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.2.jar!/webapps/cluster to /tmp/Jetty_node01_8088_cluster____.xvhrue/webapp
2016-07-19 16:19:00,391 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2016-07-19 16:19:00,396 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Starting expired delegation token remover thread, tokenRemoverScanInterval=60 min(s)
2016-07-19 16:19:00,401 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2016-07-19 16:19:01,546 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.RackResolver: Resolved node04.mydomain.de to /default-rack
2016-07-19 16:19:01,547 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.RackResolver: Resolved node03.mydomain.de to /default-rack
2016-07-19 16:19:01,547 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.RackResolver: Resolved node05.mydomain.de to /default-rack
2016-07-19 16:19:01,549 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService: NodeManager from node node03.mydomain.de(cmPort: 52286 httpPort: 8042) registered with capability: <memory:8192, vCores:8>, assigned nodeId node03.mydomain.de:52286
2016-07-19 16:19:01,557 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService: NodeManager from node node05.mydomain.de(cmPort: 39121 httpPort: 8042) registered with capability: <memory:8192, vCores:8>, assigned nodeId node05.mydomain.de:39121
2016-07-19 16:19:01,557 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService: NodeManager from node node04.mydomain.de(cmPort: 42205 httpPort: 8042) registered with capability: <memory:8192, vCores:8>, assigned nodeId node04.mydomain.de:42205
2016-07-19 16:19:01,753 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@node01:8088
2016-07-19 16:19:01,753 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Web app cluster started at 8088
2016-07-19 16:19:01,759 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl: node03.mydomain.de:52286 Node Transitioned from NEW to RUNNING
2016-07-19 16:19:01,760 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl: node05.mydomain.de:39121 Node Transitioned from NEW to RUNNING
2016-07-19 16:19:01,760 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl: node04.mydomain.de:42205 Node Transitioned from NEW to RUNNING
2016-07-19 16:19:01,762 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Added node node03.mydomain.de:52286 clusterResource: <memory:8192, vCores:8>
2016-07-19 16:19:01,762 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Added node node05.mydomain.de:39121 clusterResource: <memory:16384, vCores:16>
2016-07-19 16:19:01,763 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Added node node04.mydomain.de:42205 clusterResource: <memory:24576, vCores:24>
2016-07-19 16:19:01,809 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2016-07-19 16:19:01,809 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8033
2016-07-19 16:19:01,810 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.ResourceManagerAdministrationProtocolPB to the server
2016-07-19 16:19:01,811 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2016-07-19 16:19:01,811 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8033: starting
hduser@node01:/opt/hadoop$
```

Comment: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` => Means the server is running, so you should see a listening port

Comment: `hduser@node01:/opt/hadoop$ netstat -la | grep 8088
hduser@node01:/opt/hadoop$`

Comment: Try `sudo` on `netstat`

Comment: Unfortunately same result.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use the `'netstat -lan | grep 8088'` or `'lsof -i:8088'`